# Перенос папки на поддомен Laravel 5.1 + nginx

Tags: nginx, laravel

Есть домен структура такая:

> example.com/ru/app example.com/en/app

Хочу сделать вот так:

> ru.example.com/app en.example.com/app

Как в роутере прописать такую схему, и как мне потом прописать это все в конфиге nginx на бакэнде и apache2 на фронтенде?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В laravel нужно добавить

```
 Route::group(array('domain' => '{lang}.myapp.com'), function() {

Route::get('/', function($lang, $id) {
    // ...
   // Ваши роутеры
});});
```

В nginx добавить

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;


        root /var/www/laravel/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name myapp.com  .myapp.com;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

        location @rewrite {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
        } 

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

В итоге laravel обрабатывает запросы с myapp.com и со всех его под доменов.

**UPD**
Если nginx + apathe2

то

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;


    root /var/www/laravel/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name myapp.com  .myapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;  
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        proxy_send_timeout 120;
        proxy_read_timeout 180;
    }
}
```

В Apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
                ServerName myapp.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
                ServerAlias *.myapp.com
                SetEnv MY_LARAVEL_ENV "staging"
                <Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
                        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                                Options -MultiViews
                                RewriteEngine On
                                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                                RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
                        </IfModule>
                </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: а если за нджинксом еще и баэкенд Apache?

Comment: Добавил вариант. Проверьте

Comment: @АнтонВеселов: А зачем вам два сервера - один тяжелее другого, если можно обойтись одним - Nginx? По версии laravel видно, что у вас PHP 5.5+. Была бы 5.2, то можно было понять почему. Зачем использовать mod_php, если есть php-fpm?

Comment: Ну так нджинкс как прокси на виртуалку, апачь на виртуалке, позже сделаю nginx-nginx

Comment: Ковыраю сейчас так не работает server_name myapp.com  .myapp.com; может так ? server_name *.myapp.com;

Comment: Это зависит от версии nginx в версии 1.8 и выше так как вы описали